# Neural network with custom error function

Tags: c#, neural-network, encog, trend

I am developing a forecasting application with the use of feedforward networks. The problem I have, is that data I would like to forecast is mostly trended. Therfore, a model I am trying to develop is following:

```
y_model = f(x) + g(t)
```

Where x is input vector, f(x) is neural network, and g(t) is some trend function (ie linear, exponential) depending on time.

Most straightforward way to do this is to modify the error function, so it would include trend:

```
E=1/2 * sum(y_ideal - y_model)^2 = 1/2 * sum(y_ideal - f(x) - g(t))^2
```

As I understand, solution is teorethically quite simple, because gradient according to model parameters (neural net weights + trend model parameters) can be calculated as:

```
grad E = - sum[(y_ideal-y_model)*(grad f + grad g)]
```

I think, that there is no theoretical problem to use neural network optimization techniques to search for NN along with trend, and update trend model parameters the same way, that neural weights are being updated.

The problem is, that I didn't manage how to do this in Encog. Learning rules are quite hard to comprehense, as they are written to be as fast as possible. I think also, that neural network structure in Encog is fixed, so it's not that simple to just extend vector of parameters and rewrite error function and gradient formula.

Comment: I don't know encog but you problem is to get time in there? Why don't you expand `x` and include the time into your input?

Comment: Including time as an input gives very poor results, because it's basically extrapolation, and neural networks are very bad at extrapolating data. The other thing is, that input must be constrained to some range, due to use of sigmoidal activation function.

Comment: well I don't understand to much about NN and this stuff but why is this extrapolation if you *guess* `g(t)`? - but sorry I hope you get a good answer (interesting stuff)

Comment: It's extrapolation, because you train your model given a data ie. from time t1 to t2, and want to use it to forecast in time t3 > t2.

Answer (score 1):

To do that I believe you need to create a custom error function in Encog.  All of the propagation trainers support this (i.e. rprop, backrpop, quick and scg).  This defines how the error is calculated on each individual output neuron, not to be confused with the overall error calculation which is how closely the neural network is fitting the entire training set.

You can use the Propagation.ErrorFunction property to define a new error function.  All of the propagation trainers extend from Propagation.  Your new class should implement the IErrorFunction interface.  By default a linear error function is used, which is implemented simply as:

```
    /// <inheritdoc/>
    public void CalculateError(IMLData ideal, double[] actual, double[] error)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < actual.Length; i++)
        {
            error[i] = ideal[i] - actual[i];
        }

    }
```

Which is just expected minus actual.  You can define this error any way you like and the gradients will be used to minimize this value.